# Having a problem with adding new information to a CSV file on Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter

I have a project on python I am working on.
I need to make a program which runs CSV, matplotlib and other modules.
I have encountered a problem I can't solve, saving new info through the tkinter to the original CSV file

Mainly the problem is the "save to db" function
My entire code is :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title('DYR')
root.minsize(700, 500)  # the minimum size of the window
root.geometry('500x500')  # in what resolution the window will open at
root.configure(bg='LightBlue1')

nameLabel = Label(root, text=' Company Name',font=("Arial Bold", 12))
nameLabel.grid(column=2, row=0)
nameInput = Entry(width=30)
nameInput.grid(column=3, row=0)

idLabel= Label(root, text = 'Client ID',font=("Arial Bold", 12))
idLabel.grid(column=2, row=1)
id_input = Entry(width=9)
id_input.grid(column= 3, row=1)
addresslabel= Label(root, text = "Company Address", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
addresslabel.grid(column= 2, row= 2)
addressinput = Entry (width= 50 )
addressinput.grid(column =3 , row = 2)
fieldlabel= Label(root, text= "Filed",font=("Arial Bold", 12))
fieldlabel.grid(column=2 , row =3)
fieldcomobx =  Combobox (root)
fieldcomobx['values']= ("Choose field",'consulting','Medical','Gaming','Cyber')
fieldcomobx.current(0) #set the selected item
fieldans = fieldcomobx.get()
fieldcomobx.grid(column=3, row=3)
numberof = Label (root, text = "Number of employees", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
numberof.grid(column = 2 , row = 4)
numberin = Entry (width= 15)
numberin.grid(column = 3 , row= 4)
contactlabel=Label(root, text = "Contact", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
contactlabel.grid(column=2, row =5)
contactin = Entry (width = 15)
contactin.grid(column=3, row =5)
lastcall = Label (root, text = "Last call ",font=("Arial Bold", 12))
lastcall.grid(column = 2 , row = 6)
lastcallin = Entry (width = 15)
lastcallin.grid(column = 3 , row=6)

def cheker():#func to check if the client exsit
    import pandas as pd
    path = r"C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\Gmar\Gmar_Project.csv"
    companyName = str(nameInput.get())
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    result = df[df.Company == companyName]
    if len(result) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Cheker", "Not exist, Good luck!")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Cheker", "The client  already exists in the data base!")

btn = Button(root,text="check existence",command= cheker)
btn.grid(column=4, row = 0)

def save_to_db(): #save the information to csv
    path = r"C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\untitled\Gmar\Gmar_Project.csv"
    newRow = [str(nameInput.get()), str(id_input.get()), str(addressinput.get()),str(fieldans), str(numberin .get()),str(contactin.get()),str(lastcallin.get())]
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(newRow).T
    df2.columns = ['Company','client ID','address','field','Number of employees','contact','last call']  # df.columns
    df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=path, index_label=False, index=False)


endbtn = Button (root, text = "SAVE" ,command = save_to_db())
endbtn.grid(column =3, row=8)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having? _"I have encountered a problem I can't solve"_ is a bit too vague for us to be able to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  @BryanOakley is right: you need to tell us exactly what result you get and if it's not an obvious error, how that differs from what you expect.  Also, please put time and effort into creating a MINIMAL example!  You'll learn a lot from the effort, and we'll be able to help you better.

Comment: You're right, editing right now, basically the " def save_to_db() " isn't  working, every time I try to save it just adding " Choose field"

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `df` contains what you expect before appending to it? Have you verified that `df2` contains what you expect it to contain? What about `newRow`? Are you certain it's set to what you expect?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, and still can't tell what the problem is

Comment: Are you absolutely _certain_? It looks to me like `newRow` is always going to contain "Choose field" because that's what `fieldans` will always be.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for pointing it out, seems that I'm lost, as I don't understand how to fix that

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you should be doing more debugging yourself before asking a question here. If you had, you would realize the question wasn't "why is the wrong data being written" but rather "why is `fielddans` always the same thing?"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `fieldans` about a millisecond after you create the combobox. The user won't have had a chance to make a section.

A general rule of thumb in GUI development is that you should not fetch data until immediately before you need it.

You need to move `fieldans = fieldcomobx.get()` inside of `save_to_db` so that you get the value entered by the user rather than the default value.

You also have the problem that you're calling `save_to_db` immediately as the GUI starts rather than after the user has had a chance to enter any data.

You need to define `endbtn` like this:

```
endbtn = Button (root, text = "SAVE" ,command = save_to_db)
```

Comment: @Dean: I updated my answer to include another problem I spotted.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll go on over the code and try to spot problems if they appear  before I'll ask for help